# Flask User Session

Tags: python, flask, flask-login, flask-session

After authenticating a user, I am having trouble **keeping a user logged in as they move through the website** I have built. I have tried using cookies and sessions but I can't seem to get it to work.

I am sharing my code for login where I grab data to authenticate a user from an excel sheet that is populated at Sign Up

I locate the names of each team member to have them appear on the Team Page, which is where the user is redirected to after login

```
@app.route('/login',methods=['POST','GET'])
def login():
# get data from form
try:
    username = str(request.form['username2'])
    password2 = str(request.form['password2'])
    teamname = str(request.form['teamname'])
    print(username)
    print(password2)

    # read excel sheet
    data = pd.read_excel("C:\\Users\\290002925\\Documents\\registration.xlsx")

    for name in data['Team']:
        if name == teamname:
            team_info = data.loc[data['Team'] == teamname]
            print(team_info)
            team_info['FullName'] = team_info['FirstName'] + [' '] + team_info['LastName']
            teamroster = team_info[['FullName']].copy()
            finalteamroster = pd.DataFrame(teamroster, index=range(5))
            print(finalteamroster)
            print(len(finalteamroster))
            finalteamroster.fillna(value='', inplace=True)
            print(finalteamroster)

            amember1 = finalteamroster.at[0,'FullName']
            print(amember1)
            amember2 = finalteamroster.at[1,'FullName']
            print(amember2)
            amember3 = finalteamroster.at[2,'FullName']
            print(amember3)
            amember4 = finalteamroster.at[3,'FullName']
            print(amember4)
            amember5 = finalteamroster.at[4,'FullName']
            print(amember5)
```

This is where the authentication of the user comes in

```
    for user in data['Email']:
        #check username
        if user == username:
            passw = data.loc[data['Email'] == username]
                # check password
            print(passw)
            test2 = passw.iat[0,3]
```

This is how I wrote out ***cookies*** but I think **Session** might be more useful

```
            if test2 == password2:
                    # authenticated
                print("User is authenticated")
                response = render_template('teampage.html', teamname=teamname, member1=amember1, member2=amember2, member3=amember3, member4=amember4, member5=amember5)
                response.set_cookie('userID', username)
                return response

            else:
                print("Password is incorrect")
                return render_template('login.html')
        else:
            print("Username is incorrect")
        return render_template('index.html')

except:
    print("fail")
return render_template('login.html')
```

Code for Teampage

```
@app.route('/teampage')
def teampage():
    userid = request.cookies.get('userID')
    return render_template('teampage.html', userid=userid)
```

HTML user reference

```
{{userid}}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit hard to understand your initial code but what I understand is that you need to maintain a User session-

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
if request.method == 'GET':
    return render_template('login.html', title=': Login')
if request.method == 'POST':
   if YourMethodToCheckPassword==True:
            session['username'] = request.form['user']
            return redirect(url_for('home'))
```

And then use the Session object everywhere like-

```
@app.route('/home')
def home():
    if 'username' in session:
        return render_template("index.html", name=session['username'])
```

Inside your HTML use

```
{{ name }}
```

Comment: This was very helpful! If I am trying to store multiple data fields (team member names), how can I go about doing so?

I tried doing something a long the lines of 

 session['userID'] = username
                        session['amember1'] = amember1
                        session['amember2'] = amember2
                        session['amember3'] = amember3
                        session['amember4'] = amember4
                        session['amember5'] = amember5
                        if 'userID', 'amember1', 'amember2' in session:

Comment: Yeah, it is possible and there is an easier way. But let's help out the community by asking this as a separate question and marking my answer as the correct answer if you found it to be helpful. Thanks

Comment: FYI: you can access `session` globally with jinja2 using `{{ session['usernam'] }}` in your HTML instead of passing it to a route every time.